# Loop to write strings from specific rows of a panda dataframe into a PDF

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, fpdf

I have a blank pdf template and a pandas dataframe with some data. I want to search one column of the df for a specific pattern and if that pattern is found, take the data from that row and write it into a pdf. My search works and is able to find all of the rows with matches and I am generating a new pdf file for each row with a match. However, the second, third, etc. files still contain the data from the previous rows. I'm not sure why these strings are not being overwritten each time I go over the loop. I also tried setting each variable to None at the start of the loop but that did not help.

My df has the format...

| Title | Type | H1 | H2 | H3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| s1 | blank | -- | -- | -- |
| s2 | 261.1_1X | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| s3 | 262.1_1X | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| s4 | blank | -- | -- | -- |

My code is able to find the patterns (###.#_#X) and take the data from those rows, but the second file would still contain the data from the first row.

Here is a snippet of my code...

```
df = upload_spreadsheet(file_path, active_sheet_only=True)
text = ' '.join([str(x) for x in combine_dataframe(df)])
pattern = r'((\d+\.)(.*)(X))'
matches = text_search(text, pattern)
head1 = df.iloc[0,2]
head2 = df.iloc[0,3]
for i in matches:   #This searches through the second column to match the samples
    matchedRow = df[1].str.match(str(i))
    rows = matchedRow[matchedRow==True]
    val1 = df.iloc[rows.index[0],2]
    val2 = df.iloc[rows.index[0],3]

    newPDFname = str(df.iloc[rows.index[0],1])

    pdf2 = FPDF()
    pdf2.add_page()
    pdf2.set_font('Arial', 'B', 16)
    xoffset = pdf2.x + 20
    pdf2.x = xoffset
    pdf2.setfillcolor = (0,0,255)
    pdf2.multi_cell(0, 10, str(head1)+'    '+ str(val1), 0, 'L', fill = False)
    pdf2.x = xoffset
    pdf2.multi_cell(0, 10, str(head2)+'    '+ str(val2), 0, 'L', fill = False)

    pdf2.output('temp.pdf', 'F')
    pdf2 = PdfFileReader('temp.pdf')
        
    first_page1 = pdf1.getPage(0)
    first_page2 = pdf2.getPage(0)

    first_page1.mergePage(first_page2)
    pdf_writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
    pdf_writer.addPage(first_page1)

    with open(newPDFname+'.pdf', "wb") as filehandle_output:
        pdf_writer.write(filehandle_output)

    os.remove("temp.pdf")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you are selecting rows properly. Your code looks complicated.

You can select rows based on string pattern match with this line:

```
foo = df[df['Type'].str.match(pattern)]
```

[pandas.Series.str.match](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html)

[Pandas: Select rows that match a string](https://davidhamann.de/2017/06/26/pandas-select-elements-by-string/)

Comment: I have that command in my main function and it works if I print to the screen. The issue is only when writing to the new pdfs. See the variable named "matchedRow"

Comment: No, i got that. My point was you could seperate the row selection logic and pdf generation logic to reduce complexity. Once you have a df with selected rows, you could just iterate over that df to generate pdf.